# How to replace Koin service injection in a Ktor route test by a mocked service

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockito, ktor, koin

I want to make a test for a Ktor route that uses Koin to inject a service.  I am struggling to mock the service used by the Ktor route in my test.

Here is the Ktor **Application.kt** file

```
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(Locations) {
    }
    // Suppressed code
    installKoin(listOf(dependencyInjectionModule))

    routing {

        val eventService by inject<EventService>()

        get("/issues/{issueNumber}/events") {

            val issue = call.parameters["issueNumber"]
            val issueNumber = parseInt(issue)
            call.respond(eventService.getEventsByIssueNumber(issueNumber))
        }      
    }
    // Suppressed code
}
```

Koin is working here above, the problem is when I need to mock instead of using Koin.

Here is the **AplicationTest.kt** file

```
class ApplicationTest {

    private val eventDtoList = listOfNotNull(
        EventDto(1, "opened", "2019-03-24T21:40:18Z", 1 ),
        EventDto(2, "closed", "2019-03-28T21:40:18Z", 1 )
    )

    @Test
    fun testGettingEventsByExistingIssueNumber() {

        withTestApplication({ module(testing = true) }) {

            stopKoin()

            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/issues/1/events").apply {
                val eventService:EventService = mock {
                    onBlocking { getEventsByIssueNumber(any()) } doReturn eventDtoList
                }

                val resultList = Gson().fromJson(response.content, Array<EventDto>::class.java).asList()

                assertEquals(response.status(), HttpStatusCode.OK)
                assertThat(resultList).hasSize(2)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to mock the eventList which is returned by the service, but I when I get to this line:

```
withTestApplication({ module(testing = true) })
```

I get this exception:

```
2019-05-08 11:51:40:881 (KOIN)::[e] Error while resolving instance for class 'com.service.EventService' - error: org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No compatible definition found for type 'EventService'. Check your module definition 

org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No compatible definition found for type 'EventService'. Check your module definition

    at org.koin.core.bean.BeanRegistry.retrieveDefinition(BeanRegistry.kt:113)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry$proceedResolution$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.invoke(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry$proceedResolution$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.invoke(InstanceRegistry.kt:36)
    at org.koin.core.time.DurationKt.measureDuration(Duration.kt:8)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry.proceedResolution(InstanceRegistry.kt:84)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry.resolve(InstanceRegistry.kt:63)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry.resolve$default(InstanceRegistry.kt:48)
    at com.jaya.octovevent.ApplicationKt$module$4$$special$$inlined$inject$1.invoke(KtorRoutingExt.kt:112)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.jaya.octovevent.ApplicationKt$module$4$2.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:76)
    at com.ApplicationKt$module$4$2.invoke(Application.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$interceptCall$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:94)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$interceptCall$2.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:180)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages.interceptCall(StatusPages.kt:93)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:133)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:148)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.interceptor(Routing.kt:29)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(Routing.kt:93)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invoke(Routing.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(ContentNegotiation.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invoke(ContentNegotiation.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$2.invokeSuspend(TestApplicationEngine.kt:265)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$2.invoke(TestApplicationEngine.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$handleRequest$pipelineJob$1.invokeSuspend(TestApplicationEngine.kt:263)
    at |b|b|b(Coroutine boundary.|b(|b)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages.interceptCall(StatusPages.kt:93)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:133)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:148)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(Routing.kt:93)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(ContentNegotiation.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$2.invokeSuspend(TestApplicationEngine.kt:265)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$handleRequest$pipelineJob$1.invokeSuspend(TestApplicationEngine.kt:263)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DeferredCoroutine.await$suspendImpl(Builders.common.kt:98)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$handleRequest$1.invokeSuspend(TestApplicationEngine.kt:129)
Caused by: org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No compatible definition found for type 'EventService'. Check your module definition
    at org.koin.core.bean.BeanRegistry.retrieveDefinition(BeanRegistry.kt:113)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry$proceedResolution$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.invoke(InstanceRegistry.kt:87)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry$proceedResolution$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.invoke(InstanceRegistry.kt:36)
    at org.koin.core.time.DurationKt.measureDuration(Duration.kt:8)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry.proceedResolution(InstanceRegistry.kt:84)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry.resolve(InstanceRegistry.kt:63)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceRegistry.resolve$default(InstanceRegistry.kt:48)
    at com.ApplicationKt$module$4$$special$$inlined$inject$1.invoke(KtorRoutingExt.kt:112)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.ApplicationKt$module$4$2.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:76)
    at com.ApplicationKt$module$4$2.invoke(Application.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$interceptCall$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:94)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$interceptCall$2.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:180)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages.interceptCall(StatusPages.kt:93)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:133)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:148)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.interceptor(Routing.kt:29)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(Routing.kt:93)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invoke(Routing.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(ContentNegotiation.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invoke(ContentNegotiation.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$2.invokeSuspend(TestApplicationEngine.kt:265)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$2.invoke(TestApplicationEngine.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:278)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:63)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:157)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:23)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine$handleRequest$pipelineJob$1.invokeSuspend(TestApplicationEngine.kt:263)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:238)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

I am aware that Koin can not find the EventService implementation because I have stopped it (Koin). So how can I replace Koin injection by my mocked service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you read the following? https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/quick-references/testing-your-components/

Comment: Yes, I did and tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set up the code for testing/mocking and not trying to investigate the features of Koin then the the way I've done this is to break things down, so something like:

```
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {

    val todoService: TodoService by inject()
    moduleWithDependencies(eventService)
}

fun Application.moduleWithDependencies(eventService: EventService) {
    install(Routing) {
        eventApi(eventService)
    }
}
```

eventApi has the routes and I can then test that independently

There's an example here (not very complete) https://github.com/kevinrjones/koodoo

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  Could you give access to that repository? I will try to simulate here

Comment: Hi @JamesFreitas, sorry been away for a while. It's now public

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are starting Koin inside `Application.module()`.

It is better to start Koin **before** calling `Application.module()`. So you can initialize different dependencies in production and test environments.

This is how to start production environment:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val appEnvironment = commandLineEnvironment(args)
    startKoin { modules(initAppModule(appEnvironment.config)) }
    embeddedServer(Netty, appEnvironment).start(true)
}
```

And this is test environment:

```
fun testApp(test: TestApplicationEngine.() -> Unit) {
    withApplication(createTestEnvironment {
        config = HoconApplicationConfig(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
        startKoin { modules(initTestAppModule(config)) }
    }, {
    }, test)

    val koin = KoinContextHandler.get()
    stopKoin() // Stop koin after test
}
```

See example here: https://github.com/comm1x/ktor-boot/blob/master/src/main.kt

And there: https://github.com/comm1x/ktor-boot/blob/master/test/common/common.kt